# Merging Consecutive Assignment Rows to get Min and Max Date of Assignment in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract some information from an Oracle database. I have a select statement that currently pulls the following information:

- `ACCOUNT_ID`: unique identifier for each account. The account should always have someone assigned to it (no gaps in STRT_DT and END_DT).
- `STAFF_ID`: unique identifier for the staff member assigned to the account. The staff member will be assigned to multiple accounts at a time, and may stop working on an account for a period of time before being assigned back to it.
- `STRT_DT`: day the staff person had an assignment start on an account
- `END_DT`: day the staff person had an assignment end on an account. The account may have a final end date if it is closed, or if it is still open the value will be `NULL`
- `RANK`: indicates the order in which each assignment occurred for an account, based on the start date.

There are multiple types of assignments for staff, which results in there frequently being back to back assignments for the same staff member, as seen here:

| ACCOUNT_ID | PERSON_ID | STRT_DT | END_DT | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 223 | A | 01/01/23 | 01/10/23 | 1 |
| 223 | A | 01/10/23 | 01/14/23 | 2 |
| 223 | A | 01/14/23 | 01/16/23 | 3 |
| 223 | B | 01/16/23 | 02/02/23 | 4 |
| 223 | C | 02/02/23 | 02/13/23 | 5 |
| 223 | C | 02/13/23 | 02/19/23 | 6 |
| 223 | A | 02/19/23 | NULL | 7 |
| 461 | A | 01/10/23 | 01/23/23 | 1 |
| 461 | C | 01/23/23 | 02/14/23 | 2 |
| 461 | A | 02/14/23 | 03/11/23 | 3 |
| 461 | B | 03/11/23 | 03/29/23 | 4 |

It is possible for a staff member to have two or more periods of time on an account that are not consecutive. This is indicated by there being another person assigned to the account with a rank in between theirs. This is demonstrated with account 223, where person A ends their assignment on 1/16, there are other staff assigned to the case, and then they start again on 2/19.

I need to condense rows where there is the same `STAFF_ID` on the same `ACCOUNT_ID` consecutively so each row indicates when the staff member first started on the account and when they finally ended. The output should look like this:

| ROW_ID | ACCOUNT_ID | STAFF_ID | STRT_DT | END_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 223 | A | 01/01/23 | 01/16/23 |
| 2 | 223 | B | 01/16/23 | 02/02/23 |
| 3 | 223 | C | 02/02/23 | 02/19/23 |
| 4 | 223 | A | 02/19/23 | NULL |
| 5 | 461 | A | 01/10/23 | 01/23/23 |
| 6 | 461 | C | 01/23/23 | 02/14/23 |
| 7 | 461 | A | 02/14/23 | 03/11/23 |
| 8 | 461 | B | 03/11/23 | 03/29/23 |

I do not have access to temporary tables other than the ones that already exist in the database - which could be used if needed and have as many columns for each datatype as I would need. I mostly use select statements to pull data, so I am not very experienced with inserting into tables and updating them.

I am assuming that I need to use some kind of loop statement, but I have not used them before. Any guidance on how to structure this, links to resources, or example code would be super helpful. I really just have no idea where to start.

EDIT: As I've been working on this, I'm thinking it also might be possible to use LAG()/LEAD() or FIRST_VALUE with some partitioning but I'm also struggling to put that together. I'll update if I make any progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY account_id
  ORDER     BY strt_dt
  MEASURES
    FIRST(person_id) AS person_id,
    FIRST(strt_dt)   AS strt_dt,
    LAST(end_dt)     AS end_dt
  PATTERN (person same_person*)
  DEFINE
    same_person AS PREV(person_id) = person_id
                AND PREV(end_dt) = strt_dt
);
```

Or, on earlier versions you can use:

```sql
SELECT account_id,
       MIN(person_id) AS person_id,
       MIN(strt_dt) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY strt_dt) AS strt_dt,
       MAX(end_dt) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY strt_dt) AS end_dt
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         SUM(has_changed_grp) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY strt_dt)
           AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           CASE
           WHEN person_id = LAG(person_id)
                              OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY strt_dt)
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
           END AS has_changed_grp
    FROM   table_name t
  ) t
)
GROUP BY
       account_id,
       grp
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ACCOUNT_ID, PERSON_ID, STRT_DT, END_DT, RANK) AS
SELECT 223, 'A', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-01-10', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 223, 'A', DATE '2023-01-10', DATE '2023-01-14', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 223, 'A', DATE '2023-01-14', DATE '2023-01-16', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 223, 'B', DATE '2023-01-16', DATE '2023-02-02', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 223, 'C', DATE '2023-02-02', DATE '2023-02-13', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 223, 'C', DATE '2023-02-13', DATE '2023-02-19', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 223, 'A', DATE '2023-02-19', NULL,              7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 461, 'A', DATE '2023-01-10', DATE '2023-01-23', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 461, 'C', DATE '2023-01-23', DATE '2023-02-14', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 461, 'A', DATE '2023-02-14', DATE '2023-03-11', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 461, 'B', DATE '2023-03-11', DATE '2023-03-29', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ACCOUNT_ID | PERSON_ID | STRT_DT | END_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 223 | A | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-16 00:00:00 |
| 223 | B | 2023-01-16 00:00:00 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00 |
| 223 | C | 2023-02-02 00:00:00 | 2023-02-19 00:00:00 |
| 223 | A | 2023-02-19 00:00:00 | *null* |
| 461 | A | 2023-01-10 00:00:00 | 2023-01-23 00:00:00 |
| 461 | C | 2023-01-23 00:00:00 | 2023-02-14 00:00:00 |
| 461 | A | 2023-02-14 00:00:00 | 2023-03-11 00:00:00 |
| 461 | B | 2023-03-11 00:00:00 | 2023-03-29 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fl5u_WR2)

Comment: I'm unfortunately using Oracle Database 19c, so I don't think this applies :( This seems like a really useful method, I'm wondering if there is something similar

Comment: @Emma I said "From Oracle 12", Oracle 19 is after Oracle 18 and Oracle 12 so you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`. Here is an [Oracle 18 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pffr24Xy).

Comment: You're literally a life saver thank you so much. I have basically no formal training and definitely need to fill in some gaps in my basic technical understanding when working with Oracle SQL especially. Thank you for the extra clarification and the fiddle - I always appreciate more resources.